# How to use same div tag with different content in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use same div tag for different page displaying using html. how to use it
Ex:`<div id ="name"> if{page1}else{page2}</div>` is there any possible using if in html or give different solution plz.
when user clicks different tab the different page need to appear i used different div but click different tab it shows some empty space with the page2 i think that is page1 space.

Comment: What kind of condition? Are you using any server side scripting?

Comment: Under what condition will you display the alternative pages? Is it after the user clicks?

Comment: You cannot do if statements in html (it's a markup language). Your question is vague: you could solve this with javascript like @Alex Thomas mentioned. Please clarify with what the content is you want to put in the div for both pages, and where that content will come from.

Comment: yes,when user click different tap the page1,page2 need to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that a page might have ids `#page1` and `#page2` and the `<div>` has an id of `#brian`

you could use jquery:

```
$('#page1 #brian').html(some_html_here);
$('#page2 #brian').html(some_html_here);
```

This example may aid you - http://jsfiddle.net/wQCDR/

Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use PHP in your HTML code you can use SSI (server-side include). Basically, you can include html files within other html files. Here's a link to read more:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

you can don this usign javascript

get url first and according to that write content to particular div using

```
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = "Content";
```